# httpd-2.4.18 mod_http2 works with curl and nghttp but doesn't work with the browser

Tags: google-chrome, curl, apache2.4, http2, nghttp2

I have installed httpd-2.4.18 with nghttp 1.6.0 and curl 7.46 to work with an http2 server. It seems that the server works with http2 when I test it with Curl and nghttp comands (as you can see below), but when I use the browser( Google Chrome 47.0.2526.106) the response headers are http1 instead of http2, and the Spdy indicator is grey (should be blue). Does anybody know why?

## Commands Used

Curl command used that says me that http2 works properly:

```
eloy@eloy-OptiPlex-745:/usr/local/apache2/logs$ curl --http2 -I http://localhost
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: h2c
Connection: Upgrade

HTTP/2.0 200
date:Thu, 07 Jan 2016 21:38:06 GMT
server:Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2e
last-modified:Mon, 11 Jun 2007 18:53:14 GMT
etag:"2d-432a5e4a73a80"
accept-ranges:bytes
content-length:45
content-type:text/html
```

The same with nghttp2, it seems that http2 server is working properly with the following command:

```
eloy@eloy-OptiPlex-745:/usr/local/apache2/logs$ nghttp -uv http://localhost
[  0.000] Connected
[  0.000] HTTP Upgrade request
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: localhost
connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
upgrade: h2c
http2-settings: AAMAAABkAAQAAP__
accept: */*
user-agent: nghttp2/1.6.0


[  0.001] HTTP Upgrade response
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: h2c
Connection: Upgrade


[  0.001] HTTP Upgrade success
[  0.001] recv SETTINGS frame <length=6, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
```

Response headers from browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Thu, 07 Jan 2016 21:49:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2e
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
ETag: "2d-432a5e4a73a80"
```

Request Headers from browser:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
If-None-Match: "2d-432a5e4a73a80"
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 11 Jun 2007 18:53:14 GMT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do not support HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 upgrade requests.

The only way to use HTTP/2 from browsers is via TLS and ALPN.

Having said that, your "Request headers from browser" above are actually *response* headers and viceversa, so it's difficult to tell what you are actually doing. The request headers lack the necessary upgrade bits.

If you make a clear-text request from a browser (i.e. using the `http` scheme), then the browser will not try to upgrade and you will stay in HTTP/1.1 mode.

Comment: Thank you so much sbordet, I have edited the mistake you said about the headers (Bad copy/paste from the browser).